# Error when start Solr cloud, due to location of 3rd party libraries

Tags: exception, solr, classpath, solrcloud

I tried to migrate to Solr 3.1 , my project uses Dataimport handler ,
when I started solr it asked me SolrCoreAwar not found I copied the following file to lib directory
apache-solr-dataimporthandler-3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 
but again an error appeared when stating solr
I need to fix this problem , if you can help
Thank You

The next message is the exception I get When Starting Solr 3.1

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler.<clinit>(DataImportHandler.java:72)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:373)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:423)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createRequestHandler(SolrCore.java:459)
    at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers.initHandlersFromConfig(RequestHandlers.java:154)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:563)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:458)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:316)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:207)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:130)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:713)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:985)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:194)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:534)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:441)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:119
```

**Update**

I've added the following jar files to my class path , the previous exception disappeared , but  a new Error appeared when starting solr server :

```
 Error Instantiating Request Handler, org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler is not a org.apache.solr.request.SolrRequestHandler
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:425)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createRequestHandler(SolrCore.java:459)
    at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers.initHandlersFromConfig(RequestHandlers.java:154)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:563)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:458)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:316)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:207)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:130)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:713)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:985)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:194)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:534)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:441)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:119)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is now solved.

This problem occurred because dataimporthandler and requesthandler are loaded by two different class loaders. To solve it, ensure that solr loads its jars only from the same class loader.

First of all I ensured that :

1) In solrconfig.xml remove ensure that dataimporthandler only comes from one place 
 2) I have commented all  directives and added new one that refers to lib directory in solr directory so the lib directory path is `example/solr/lib` , this directory doesn't exists by default. Create it (for example using `mkdir solr/lib`) and the lib directive in `solrconfig.xml` becomes

> ```
> <lib dir="./solr/lib"/>
> ```

3) Add the jar file from dist directory to this directory example/solr/lib
 4) Fire up your solr server

And don't forget to copy your mysql-driver jar to your include path to be able to index your mysql database tables if you use dataimporthandler for this purpose

**Note: This works for solr 4.0**

Comment: I think you saved my sanity. Thanks for taking the time to post your own solution.

Comment: Mother of god. This was it. My custom ResponseHandler will only load if it's NOT in the solr/lib/ directory. I just put it somewhere else and added a new <lib> directive for it, and everything works.

Comment: If I understood your solution: you have commented out all lib directives in solrconfig.xml ? And put only one lib directive for lib. I did just like that and my only directive is: <lib dir="../../../lib" regex=".*\.jar" /> . When I try to insert document into solr, I receive error 'Error instantiating Request Handler'

Comment: Adding the solr-solrj-5.5.0.jar to the lib directory worked for solr-5.5.0

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most probably deeper, but you could try putting slf4j apis in your class path. (http://www.slf4j.org/download.html).

Comment: I tired this but no effect at all

Answer (score 0):

@see [SOLR-2574](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2574) for a solution and sample working project. It's for Solr 3.2 but it works with Sorl 3.1 too.

In short, add a dependency on slf4j-nop.

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of months later, you may get the response.

Had the exact same issue and I was able to get over it by actually using absolute paths to the data import handler.

Answer (score 0):

#solr 3.5 : The classloader issue has been correctly identified above, but the solution didn't seem to work for me. I just put the dataimporthandler jars into the solr.war file and that worked, of course.