# solr cloud - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/util/TokenizerFactory

Tags: java, solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

When start solr cloud with external zookeeper cluster, got error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/util/TokenizerFactory

I checked the configuration, but didn't found any error.

The additional 3rd party jars are added at: `solr-6.2.0-cloud/server/lib/ext`, is that a problem ?

What could possibly be the reason? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue.

**Reason:**

Didn't add 3rd party jars in a proper location, and caused jvm not be able to find some class.

This seems to be a special requirement when run in solr cloud mode.

**Solution:**

First put jars in `$SOLR_BASE/dist`, or other proper location.

Then specify location of additional jar via `<lib>` tag in `solrconfig.xml`.

```
e.g
    <lib dir="../../../dist/ext/" regex="jcseg-analyzer-\d.*\.jar" />
    <lib dir="../../../dist/ext/" regex="jcseg-core-\d.*\.jar" />
    <lib dir="../../../dist/ext/" regex="postgresql-\d.*\.jar" />
```

Then upload the config to zookeeper, reload the solr collection, then it will work.

**Refer:**

- [Error when start Solr cloud, due to location of 3rd party libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874917)
- [org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913915)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't need any external jar for setup external zookeeper. it may be because of other changes you made in solr config fie or schema file

[How to setup external zookeeper with solr](http://jayant7k.blogspot.in/2013/06/step-by-step-setting-up-solr-cloud.html)

Comment: I added the jar for jdbc & customized lucene analyser, not for zookeeper. Before I add the jars, it works. I am wondering whether the additional jars effected the classloader and caused the issue.